# How to autorepeat a set of chained UIView animations using UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to chain a set of `UIView animateWithDuration:` using the flag `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`
The animation steps I am trying to repeat are:

1. Animate a `UIView` 100 pixels to the left
2. Fade the `UIView` out (opacity `'0'`)
3. While faded out (invisible), move it back to the original position (100 px to the right)
4. Fade the `UIView` back in (set opacity to `'1'`)
5. Repeat the animation using flag `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`

I am not able to repeat the whole chain of animations - and only able to repeat the top most animation.

The code I have tried is this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        self.handImageView.frame = CGRectMoveByXPixels(self.handImageView.frame, -100);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:1 options:0 animations:^{
            self.handImageView.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.handImageView.frame = CGRectMoveByXPixels(self.handImageView.frame, 100);
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
                self.handImageView.alpha = 1;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an animation that uses `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` never finishes and therefore never calls the `completion` block.  However, you can repeat the animations using the `performSelector` method, as shown in the code below.

```
- (void)repeatingAnimationForView:(UIView *)view
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:0
    animations:^{ view.frame = CGRectMoveByXPixels(view.frame, -100); }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {  if ( finished )  {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0
    animations:^{ view.alpha = 0; }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {  if ( finished )  {

    view.frame = CGRectMoveByXPixels(view.frame, 100);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0
    animations:^{ view.alpha = 1; }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {  if ( finished )  {

    if ( self.enableRepeatingAnimation )
        [self performSelector:@selector(repeatingAnimationForView:) withObject:view afterDelay:0];

    }}]; }}]; }}];
}

- (void)stopRepeatingAnimationForView:(UIView *)view
{
    self.enableRepeatingAnimation = NO;
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
    view.frame = CGRectMake( 100, 137, 80, 50 );
    view.alpha = 1;
}

- (void)startRepeatingAnimationForView:(UIView *)view
{
    self.enableRepeatingAnimation = YES;
    [self repeatingAnimationForView:view];
}
```

To stop the animations immediately, call the `stopRepeatingAnimationForView` method as shown above. To stop the animations at the end of a cycle, simply set `self.enableRepeatingAnimation` to `NO`.

Comment: but then I cant stop it any time using view.layer [removeAllAnimations]

Comment: @AvnerBarr ok, fixed that for you.

Comment: Cool - so just create a mechanism for starting and stoping the recursive animation

Comment: @AvnerBarr performSelector doesn't seem available in Swift. How could you chain repeating UIView animations in Swift?