# Swift: chain UIView animations that repeat forever? Obj-C code not portable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation, uiview

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360940/how-to-autorepeat-a-set-of-chained-uiview-animations-using-uiviewanimationoption) describes how to chain repeating UIView animations in Objective-C. However, it requires `performSelector`, which doesn't appear to be available in Swift.

How can you chain repeating UIView animations in Swift? The goal is to create an animation to shake/wobble a UIView.

Comment: Have you tried animations with `animateWithDuration` and then set the `options` block to `.Repeat`?

Comment: Yes @CeceXX but .Repeat means the other animations never get called because the completion block never gets called.

Comment: Can't you place your code inside a function and then call the function in the completion block?

Comment: I agree @Crashalot I don't know why the downvotes?? This is a very valid question, and NO the answers below don't answer the question -- if you use .Repeat with an animation--**the completion block never gets called!!** just like the author stated. If anyone knows how to repeat animations that are already Chained then please do answer

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var wobble = true

func wobbleLeft() {

    if !wobble {
        return
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        // Animate wobble to left
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.wobbleRight()
    }
}

func wobbleRight() {

    if !wobble {
        return
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        // Animate wobble to right
        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.wobbleLeft()
    }
}
```

Start by calling `wobbleLeft()`, then it will call `wobbleRight()` when it's completed. To stop the wobble, just set `wobble = false`

Comment: How does this sequence repeat? Thanks for the help!